# Angular JS Mathml views not processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax, mathml

I have an app that displays views with Mathml. The Math tags are not getting processed. I have to refresh the page for them to be processed.

My view contain one controller and MathMl tags like :

**moment-lone.html**:

```
 <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
   <msub><mi>I</mi><mn>x</mn></msub><mtext>&nbsp;et&nbsp;</mtext><msub><mi>I</mi><mn>y</mn></msub> 
 </math>
```

**Angular app routing to view.html**

```
var mid = angular.module('mid', [
  'ngRoute'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/moment", {templateUrl: "moment-lone.html", controller: "momentCtrl"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: 'index'});
}]);
```

The app is working. However the expected tags are not processed by mathjax because it loaded before the tags. And this is using Chrome. In firefox they are visible on load. I think Firefox have native support for mathml.

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you mean by "not getting processed"? What's your input? What's your expected result? Show a complete example of code you have problems with. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I see plain text in the page instead of the mathml format. This one line would look like "Ix et Iy"

Comment: You have to tell MathJax to rerender the content of the website when the view is changed.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: `MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Rerender'])` according to MathJax documentation. Try reading it https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.0-latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.data = '<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac bevelled="true"><mrow><mo>(</mo><msup><mi>B</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#177;</mo><msqrt><mn>4</mn><mi>a</mi><mi>c</mi></msqrt><mo>)</mo></mrow><mrow><mn>2</mn><mi>A</mi></mrow></mfrac></math></p>';
```

in HTML

```
<div ng-bind-html="mathmltext(title)"></div>
```

in app.js

```
$scope.mathmltext= function(html_code){       
return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
```

}

Don't forget to give $sce in controller like

```
app.controller("Cntrl", function($scope,$sce) {
```

}

you can get the output like

(B2±4ac)2A